# NTILES funtion not working in R

Tags: r

I am new to R I would like to know how I can set the RANGE in `RANK()` function. Basically I need to rank my data with `RANK()` function is there a way to do it?

I have also tried with `NTILES()` function which is throwing an error like `"FUNCTION NTILES NOT FOUND"`. I have also tried to download the function but the package is also not available for `R3.1.2`

Please let me know if there is a solution like `NTILES`

Comment: You need to show what you've tried so far

Comment: Look at `?rank` and `?quantile`.

Comment: it would be helpful if you would tell us what `NTILES()` is supposed to do (I presume it's an Excel-like function?)

Comment: Ntiles is nothing like a Percentile but it depends on what value you give in ntile. For Example you have 100 records in a DF and use NTILES(5), Ntiles will divide the 100 records into 20% each and gives the rank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a dataframe called `df`, you can add a rank column, based on column `someCol`, like this:

```
df <- cbind(df, rank = rank(df$someCol))
```

R functions are case-sensitive, so that might be why you're having problems.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Can I set the range to for the rank like 1:10 so that all my data is set with a rank between 1-10.          or do I have an alternate of NTILES function in R

Comment: You could re-scale a column in your dataset using `scale`. The following function rescales the rank from 0-10: `df$score <- scale(df$rank, center = min(df$rank), scale = max(df$rank) - min(df$rank)) * 10`.

Answer (score 1):

To work with NTILES in R we need to install a package " schoRsch "

syntax for NTILE:

data.frame$RANK=ntiles(data.frame, dv="var1", bins=10)